# Consumption Plan Azure Functions Transient Failures

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-sql-database

During heavy load my consumption azure functions are timing out with the following errors-

**1.System.InvalidOperationException : An exception has been raised that is likely due to a transient failure. Consider enabling transient error resiliency by adding 'EnableRetryOnFailure()' to the 'UseSqlServer' call. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException : The client was unable to establish a connection because of an error during connection initialization process before login. Possible causes include the following:  the client tried to connect to an unsupported version of SQL Server; the server was too busy to accept new connections; or there was a resource limitation (insufficient memory or maximum allowed connections) on the server. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.) ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception : An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.**

**2.System.InvalidOperationException : Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to obtaining a connection from the pool.  This may have occurred because all pooled connections were in use and max pool size was reached.**

We are using Azure SQL database P4 with 500 DTUs. My initial thought was that due to less available worker threads it might be failing. But, they are well within limit with max at 12%.
We know that some of out LINQ queries are slow and are not performing well, but that would require business logic change.

Is there any solution on Azure Infrastructure side or any logs I can look into to?

Answer (score 0):

We had first problem couple of month ago, we just added EnableRetryOnFailure() on database configuration, it resolved the first issue. Sample code given below

```
    var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<KasDbContext>();
    optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(getConnectionString(), options =>
    {
        options.EnableRetryOnFailure(maxRetryCount: Constants.MaxRetryCountOnDbTransientFailure, maxRetryDelay: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(Constants.MaxDelaySecondsOnDbTransientFailure), errorNumbersToAdd: null);
    });
    return new DbContext(optionsBuilder.Options);
```

Comment: did it have any positive response on the overall performance of the db like success rates , response time ?

Comment: It won't increase any performance, if any errors(SQL Exeception) happening while initializing connection, It will retry.